# How can I look up MOSEK symbolic constants at run time?

Tags: c, optimization, mosek

Most of the mosek options that take an integer value as an argument have some symbolic constants associated with them. For instance, MSK_IPAR_CPU_TYPE can be MSK_CPU_POWERPC_G5, MSK_CPU_INTEL_PM etc.  These values are macros defined in mosek.h.  However, I know it must be possible to look them up at run time because the precompiled mosek executable can do it.  How?

Comment: Probably some kind of lookup table, one for each type of thing.

Comment: I assume there is a function that can do it but I can't find it...makes it hard to set options on run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out...
`MSK_putnaintparam`, `MSK_putnastrparam` e.g. the put functions with na in them let you pass in the name.